# Reading Mifare Classic 1K data

Tags: ios, mifare

I've searched a lot but I didn't a good solution or article about reading Mifare Classic 1K data in iOS.

How can I achieve that? Really I don't know anything so please excuse me if the question is a little bit unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS devices lack the necessary hardware to communicate with NFC tags. 
You will only be able to read Mifare tags with an external accessory. 
Try investigating iCarte and Flomio or the Android platform.

Comment: It is also worth noting that even if you have a NFC reader, MiFare Classic data is by default encrypted - although the encryption has been broken, it is still not trivial to read it.